# K8s Inter-service communication via FQDN

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have two services deployed to a single cluster in K8s.  One is IS4, the other is a client application.

[According to leastprivilege](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3568#event-2588006001), the internal service must also use the FQDN.

The issue I'm having when developing locally (via `skaffold` & `Docker`) is that the internal service resolves the FQDN to `127.0.0.1` (the cluster).  Is there any way to ensure that it resolves correctly and routes to the correct service?

Another issue is that internally the services communicate on HTTP, and publicly they expose HTTPS.  With a URL rewrite I'm able to resolve the DNS part, but I'm unable to change the HTTPS calls to HTTP as NGINX isn't called, it's a call direct to the service.  If there is some inter-service ruleset I can hook into (similar to ingress) I believe I could use that to terminate TLS and things would work.

Edit for clarification:
I mean, I'm not deploying to AKS.  When deployed to AKS this isn't an issue.

HTTPS is explosed via NGingx ingress, which terminates TLS.

Comment: What do you mean with "*developing locally*" with Skaffold and Docker? Isn't the application automatically deployed in the cluster via Skaffold? Please elaborate on that as by default, every [pod and service running in the cluster are assigned an IP address and a FQDN](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#what-things-get-dns-names), and they're configured to resolve using the internal DNS system (i.e. KubeDNS/CoreDNS).

Comment: Additionally, is not clear when you say that services are exposed using HTTPS. Exposed via Ingress/LoadBalancer or is the service being served internally via an Nginx service? Please elaborate in that part for accurate advise.

Comment: @YahirHernández - Updated.